# How to change state for individual buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, list, button, state, disable

I have a question about rendering based on conditions in React. I have this button component here that renders a list of buttons based on an API list of "ranks". When you press a button it will update a users rank to the new one. The catch is that they cannot be deranked through the same process, so whenever a user is placed at a certain rank, they cannot select any button lower than the current rank value. It looks like so:

```
interface BProps {
  data: Array<any>;
  buttonAction: any; //action for parent component
  rank: string;
  rankId: number;

}

interface BState {
  data: Array<any>;
  rankId: integer;
  rank: string;
  
}


export default class rankButtons extends React.Component<BProps, BState> {
  router: any;
  
  constructor(props: BProps) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        rankId: this.props.rankId,
        rank: this.props.rank,
            
      }

      this.updateRank = this.updateRank.bind(this);
    }


    updateRank(element) { 
      const { id, value } = element.target; 
      let headers: any = {//calls headers};
      var payload = {//payload};
      //get facade
      assignNewRank(payload, headers).then(()=>{
        //call buttonAction function.
        this.props.buttonAction(
          id, value
        )
      }).catch((e: any)=>{})

      this.pageUpdate()
    
    }

    pageUpdate(){
      //window.location.reload()
      
  }
      
      getData = () => {
      //Make API Call};
        let payload: any = {}
        getReferenceValues(payload, headers).then((res:any)=>{
        this.setState({
          data: res.data,
       })
        }).catch((e: any)=>{})
      }
  
      componentDidMount(){
          this.getData();
          this.setState({rank: this.props.rank}, () => {});
      }

      
    render() { 
      return(
        <div> 
          <h5>User Rankings:</h5> 
          <div className='buttonContainer'>
            {this.state.data.map((rank =>  
                <li key={rank.key}>
                  <button id={rank.key} value = {rank.text} onClick={this.updateRank} disabled={rank.key <= this.state.rankId ? true : false}>
                    {rank.text}
                  </button>
                </li>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
          
        )
            
      }
    }
```

Currently the functionality works, I am able to update a users rank whenever one of the buttons is pressed. However I have set the buttons to disable with: `disabled={rank.key <= this.state.rankId ? true : false}` The problem with this is that I don't see the buttons become disabled unless I refresh the page. I have set it so that when you press a button the entire page refreshes, which works but it feels sloppy.

I know that in react you usually have to update the state in order for it to re-render components, but I am not sure how to do this in a similar method to what I have here. In short, it works how I want it, but I need the buttons to become disabled once the value changes without having to refresh the page.

Comment: hey, but you are not updating the state in updateRank, so instead of this.pageUpdate just update the state with new values

Comment: Could you elaborate? what should I pass as the new values to update? is it the same as the condition I set for disable?

Comment: why do you need state? to keep some information in app memory and then change it when you need it. I suppose when a user clicks a button - something has to change, what exactly - only you know. However, I believe it should mimic your assignNewRank server call

Answer (score 0):

Your updateRank function doesn't update the components state, so rankId doesn't change, it seems only to update your server (?).
Either your container component has to pass the rankId as prop and remove it from component state so you reference it as `this.props.rankId` instead of `this.state.rankId` or you need to update your rank within your updateRank function.

Comment: Wow that did it! Sometimes it really is as simple a mistake as passing state instead of props, nice catch. Thank you for the help.